# Is it possible within a formula field to test whether a Lead has open activities?

Tags: formula-field, activities

I am writing "Priority Score" formula field to help our reps prioritize leads, which outputs a number.  If a lead has no open activities I want to give it a higher score; is it possible to evaluate that within the formula logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that you would need a roll up field for activities on the Lead object.  Unfortunately you can't use the standard rollup summary field with the activities object.  You could use some Apex triggers to monitor this your self, or look on the app exchange for some products that do this.

For monitoring yourself through apex there are a few good designs already out there that I would take a look at

One by Anthony Victorino that I have used before and it works well can be found [here](http://www.anthonyvictorio.com/salesforce/roll-up-summary-utility/)

One by Andrew Fawcett that I haven't personally used but I have read and heard excellent things about it. Can be found [here](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/07/new-tool-declarative-rollups-for-lookups/)

If you wanted to avoid coding you could take a look at the rollup helper app on the app exchange, found [here](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI).

No matter what route you go, you will then have a field on the lead for number of activities and you can use that in the logic of your formula.

Comment: Thanks sfdc_ninja, that is really helpful.  Our organization just upgraded to EE so I am just getting my feet wet with Apex, but I will try the designs you suggest and see what works.

Comment: No prob.  If you want to give yourself some breathing room, I would start with the declarative options, the rollup helper, using the free trial.  Then you can play with the apex solutions in a sandbox until you get comfortable with them.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do this without apex. Leads is a parent to Activities (one to many relationship) and the only way to get information from many child activities onto the parent is if they are summarized. You can do this aggregation is one of two ways, either with a Rollup Summary Field (which is not an option in this case) or with an apex rollup of some sort, either using a trigger, batch or combination of the two. Without that summary field, which requires some apex, it won't be possible to create that formula field.